# Password show/hide toggle deletes password TextField value (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, textfield, setstate

When I click on show/hide toggle, both password and username textfield values gets deleted. I understand that, when setState rebuilds the widget tree, it resets password/username textfield values to initial blank values. I know I can get value of textfield, However I am not able to implement logic, how can I first get current username and password value, save it somewhere and then insert it back at the time widget rebuilds alongwith setState.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  bool _showPassword = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final usernameController = TextEditingController();
    final passwordController = TextEditingController();
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Image(image: AssetImage('images/logo.png')),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      controller: usernameController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Enter Username",
                        labelText: "UserName",
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      obscureText: _showPassword,
                      controller: passwordController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Enter Password",
                        labelText: "Password",
                        suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: _togglePasswordVisibility,
                          child: _showPassword
                              ? Icon(Icons.visibility)
                              : Icon(Icons.visibility_off),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        //call api here to authenticate user
                      },
                      child: Text("Login"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Don't have an account! Get it in 2 easy steps"),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      //take user to registration screen
                    },
                    child: Text("Register"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _togglePasswordVisibility() {
    setState(() {
      _showPassword = !_showPassword;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the setState to toggle the visibility, the build method will get called to redraw that widget. Since you are initialising your `TextEditingController` in the build method, it get initialised again and loose the previous value. To fix this you just remove the initialisation from build method to class level.

```
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  bool _showPassword = true;
  final usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return SafeArea(
        //... Your code
    );
  }
  //... Your code
}
```

Comment: I think need to add dispose()

Comment: @someuser Yes, he need to implement the dispose method and in that he need to dispose the texteditingcontrollers as well

Comment: @MidhunMP this worked! I knew how build was getting redrawn but in a silly way simply could not figure out that I could take those 2 variables out of build. Noob level 100%.

Comment: @MidhunMP why do I need to implement dispose() and put controller in that? So that memory location resource occupied by controller variable can be freed?

Comment: @PriyankSharma Yes, for freeing the allocated resources